# How do I re-write this contact button code so it works?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a contact button on my website with the below coding, however it is not opening up an email page as desired. I was wondering if anyone would be able assist me in re-writing the code so that it works.

I would like the existing styling and id's to remain. Basically I can't get it to work sadly.

```css
#contact-button{
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-right: 33px;
 padding-left: 28px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-style: lato;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 margin-right: 2px;
 margin-left: 245px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.90;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#contact-button {
    background-color: #F06000; 
    color: white; 
}

#contact-button:hover {
 color: white;
 background-color: #A74200;
}

#mail-icon{
 margin-top: 6px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:#" id="contact-button">Message Me
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAA3ElEQVQ4T6WTaw3CQBCEZxzgAHCAhEpAQnGAlKIAcIADQAFIQAIOhsxmr2lKQ0q7fy697Hw3+ygxMzhTD0qqAGgqyACLXwDOf0JqAEsDbgkQyd0YiKRT5q0CQLKStAfgcmqS7yGQpAWAI4A7ySa0BWCBJNsKUB+S4iuAA8lw8AXIyw2AxiCSz86dRXYXd2MAtmtHDotdVgsdBHRLSOElz22ebngzWEI20fb9SjQx60bv2+U9SB7aHuQYnVgs/5xmjtH7sy6L5MYUu2NWwTl+LPbAs58c83+myU+n8AOSyY9qfRA3mgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Mail Icon" id="mail-icon" />
</a>
```

Comment: What is happening when you click it?

Comment: When I click it, it attempts to start an email. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: Mail popup is opening already, so its right. What do you want to fix?

Comment: @cal - You might want to obfuscate your email address in the question and answers...

Comment: @cal - Your button works on my machine. Do you maybe not have a default email client defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the space from before the mailto:

`mailto: joebloggs@gmail.com`

should be

`mailto:joebloggs@gmail.com`

---

**SNIPPET**

```css
#contact-button{
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-right: 33px;
 padding-left: 28px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-style: lato;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 margin-right: 2px;
 margin-left: 245px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.90;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#contact-button {
    background-color: #F06000; 
    color: white; 
}

#contact-button:hover {
 color: white;
 background-color: #A74200;
}

#mail-icon{
 margin-top: 6px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:joebloggs@gmail.com" id="contact-button">Message Me
</a>
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, really appreciate your response.